# Write a new value on post build event property on Visual Studio

Tags: vsix

i want to modify the start external program property value, on the visual studio project property, but i can't find the correct name.

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
string command = "C:\myprogram.exe"
envDTE = project.DTE;

EnvDTE.Properties configmg = project.Properties;
configmg.Item("????").Value = command;
}
```

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution to my problem. The property name is **PostBuildEvent** .
The code bellow will set the property to value defined in *Command*.

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
string command = "C:\myprogram.exe"
envDTE = project.DTE;

EnvDTE.Properties configmg = project.Properties;
configmg.Item("PostBuildEvent").Value = command;
}
```